# DataGridTemplateColumn Color

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wpfdatagrid

I am attempting to create a column in a DataGrid which is nothing more than a rectangle with a solid color.  This column is defined with the following XAML.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MeasurementGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Azure" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          HeadersVisibility="Column" VerticalGridLinesBrush="AntiqueWhite"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="AntiqueWhite">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>                                
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Energy" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Path=Energy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field Size" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=FieldSize}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Path=FriendlyType}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Depth" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Path=Depth}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that although my data source for this grid does have a property named "Color", the solidcolorbrush as defined in my XAML is not utilizing this value.  As can be seen, I do have other columns which are bound also, and do bind appropriately at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Being new to WPF, the problem wasn't obivous at the beginning.  My custom data object to which this DataGrid was being bound has a property named "Color" of type System.Drawing.Color.  As WPF utilizes System.Windows.Media.Color, I was forced to create a value converter class of my own.  Here it is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfTchartTest.Converters
{
    class WinFormsColorToWpfColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color color = (System.Drawing.Color)value;

            System.Windows.Media.Color converted = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(
                color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);

            return converted;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I only had to add this as a resource to my user interface and use the following syntax upon binding to the WinForms "Color"...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <conv:WinFormsColorToWpfColorConverter x:Key="WinFormsColorToWpfColor" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=WinFormsColorToWpfColor}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this one.

I created a new WPF Application in Visual C# Express 2010, copied your DataGrid into MainWindow.xaml, and modified the code in MainWindow.xaml.cs to contain the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Color> colors = new List<Color>() { Colors.Red, Colors.Green, Colors.Blue };
            MeasurementGrid.ItemsSource = colors.Select(color => new Colored() { Color = color }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Colored
    {
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I ran the application, I got a grid with coloured rectangles down the first column.

(In a real application, the class `Colored` would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `colors` would be an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`.  For the purposes of this demo, we'll leave such details aside.)

Comment: I solved my own problem.  The issue was that the property to which I was binding, "Color" was of type System.Drawing.Color.  I had to create a value converter.